# How to pove this identity with sum

Tags: summation

show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{\Gamma{(k+1)}}{\Gamma{(k+1-a)}}x^{k-a}\right)=\dfrac{\Gamma{(n+1)}}{\Gamma{(n+1-a)}}(1+x)^{n-a}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{\Gamma{(k+1)}}{\Gamma{(k+1-a)}}x^{k-a}\right)
 & = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}\dfrac{\Gamma{(k+1)}}{\Gamma{(k+1-a)}}x^{k-a}\right)  & (\ast)
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^{k-a}}{\Gamma(n-k+1)\Gamma(k+1-a)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1-a)}\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-a}{k-a}x^{k-a} & (\ast)
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1-a)}\sum_{j=0}^{n-a} \binom{n-a}{j}x^{j} & (\star)
\\[1ex] & =\dfrac{\Gamma{(n+1)}}{\Gamma{(n+1-a)}}(1+x)^{n-a} & (\dagger)\end{align}$$

---

$(\ast)$ since $\dbinom{n}{k} = \dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\;\Gamma(n-k+1)}$

$(\star)$ by convention, $\dbinom{\;\lvert N\rvert}{{-}\lvert M\rvert}=0$

$(\dagger)$ it's the *binomial expansion*: $(1+x)^m = \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}{j}x^j$